# Loading mysql file to rds database in AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have database inside `aws ec2 instance`. I like to transfer that ec2 instance's database to rds database.

From Phpmyadmin, `database.sql` file is exported firstly.

I have that file `database.sql` copied to the instance's ~/ folder.

Then login to mysql as

```
 mysql -h database.cqqqzagkqjoe.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u testdatabase -p
```

Then the `database.sql` file was imported as

mysql> mysql -u username -p database < database.sql

After that I got error as

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u username -p database < database.sql' at line 1
```

What is wrong with that message?

Comment: Well what is on line 1 of the SQL file that the error message is complaining about? How can we help without seeing the line of SQL that the error message is about? I'm guessing it has something to do with account names since you have a different admin user account on RDS than you would on a MySQL instance you created yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Do not log into the MySQL server as client, execute the SQL file.**

So, from the EC2 instance itself:

```
mysql -h database.cqqqzagkqjoe.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u testdatabase -p < database.sql
```